# Why is iterating over pages return by a paginator so slow with boto3?

Tags: python, pagination, boto3

I am using boto3 to retrieve resources from an AWS infrastructure. My code is pulling functions from all 16 regions. I was curious about why it was so slow (around 20 seconds). While investigating, I realized the following line of code was the bottleneck:

```py
pages = client.get_paginator(paginator_name).paginate(**paginator_args)
client = AWSFacadeUtils.get_client(service, region)
pages = client.get_paginator(paginator_name).paginate(**paginator_args))

resources = []
for page in pages: # This is hella slow
    resources.extend(page[key])

return resources
```

Why is iterating over the pages so slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why iterating over the pages is so slow is that you aren't only iterating over the resources, you are pulling the resources.

From the documentation, here's what `paginator`says:

> **paginate(**kwargs)**
>
> Create paginator object for an operation.
>
> This returns an iterable object. Iterating over this object will yield a 
>      single page of a response at a time.

Comment: Do you mean that the pagination also fetch the ressource itself ? What can I do if I only want to list the content of my bucket under a specific prefix without pulling them ?